# Escaping a single quote in java and trying to render the escaped quote in a json blob

Tags: java, javascript, regex, grails, escaping

In my web application, I am trying to build a JSON string on the server and then pass this to the client so I can process it with some client side javascript. This works most of the time, however when the JSON string contains a single quote, the javascript breaks.

The JSON is basically a list of maps, which is passed into my GSP page in the `mappings` variable. I then evaluate the string to convert it into a javascript object:

```
var json = eval('(${mappings})');
```

When `mappings` is evaluated, the complete javascript expression looks something like this:

```
var json = eval('([{"targetId":123,"targetName":"this isn't going to work"}])');
```

So clearly, in this case when `mappings` contains a single quote ("...this *isn't* going to work..."), the JSON string is terminated prematurely and the browser reports a javascript error.

I would have expected this to be easy to work around, however on the java side, when I try to replace `'` with `\'` using

```
json.replaceAll("'", "\\'")
```

I get this:

```
"...this isn't going to work..."
```

i.e. it doesn't change at all!

If I try to double escape the backslash, i.e.

```
json.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'")
```

I get this:

```
"...this isn\\'t going to work..."
```

Which isn't correct either. How can I replace the single quote with a single backslash and quote so that when the string is rendered on the client it can be evaluated properly?

Comment: Why not use `${mappings.encodeAsJavaScript()}` The codecs exists for a reason. See: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.1/guide/security.html But doing eval() is a waste anyways. (See Amadan's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `eval`. If you're inserting a JSON string into JavaScript, just insert it.

```
var json = ${mappings};
```

No escaping needed, the string is already valid JavaScript. (And if you do ever need to parse JSON, please use `JSON.parse()` and not `eval()`. It slows down your code significantly.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex here. Just use `String#replace` method to escape single quotes:

```
String repl = "this isn't going to work".replace("'", "\\'");
//=> this isn\'t going to work
```

#### [Code Demo](http://ideone.com/w2eeOt)